# Regex equivalent to str.substr(0, str.indexOf('foo'))

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Given this string:

```
var str = 'A1=B2;C3,D0*E9+F6-';
```

I would like to retrieve the substring that goes from the beginning of the string up to `'D0*'` (excluding), in this case:

```
'A1=B2;C3,'
```

I know how to achieve this using the combination of the `substr` and `indexOf` methods:

```
str.substr(0, str.indexOf('D0*'))
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/XSu22/

However, this is obviously not the best solution since it contains a redundancy (the `str` name has to be written twice). This redundancy can be avoided by using the `match` method together with a regular expression that captures the substring:

```
str.match(/???/)[1]
```

Which regular expression literal do we have to pass into `match` to ensure that the correct substring is returned?

My guess is this: `/(.*)D0\*/` (and that [works](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/XSu22/1)), but my experience with regular expressions is rather limited, so I'm going to need a confirmation...

Comment: The combination of `substr` and `indexOf` may have redundancy, but it is [far quicker](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-match).

Comment: @lonesome I hate redundancy more than I love performance `:)`

Comment: @lonesomeday - http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-match/2 in Chrome, at least, my regex is faster than `substr` and `indexOf` :)

Comment: okay, apparently only in chrome.  FF `substr` is 10x faster than the regex

Comment: `slice()` is better than `substr()` because it's standardized while `substr()` is not, and it works correctly in all browsers whereas `substr()` had some issue with negative character indexes in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(.*?)D0\*/.exec(str)[1]
```

Or:

```
str.match(/(.*?)D0\*/)[1]
```

## [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/XSu22/3/)

> `?` directly following a quantifier makes the quantifier non-greedy (makes it match minimum instead of maximum of the interval defined).
>   [Here's where that's from](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^.*(?=D0\*)/
```

more text to hit character limit...

Comment: So, if we wrap `DO\*` in a non-capturing group, then the `match` method returns the desired substring directly, right?

Comment: @Šime - It's actually a look-ahead, not a non-capturing group (not quite the same thing).  But yes, the entire match, or `.match[0]` will be the part before `D0*`, or you can flip it if so desired to `/^.*(?=D0\*)/.exec(str)[0]`.  This also acts as a non-greedy regex due to the look-ahead, which is why it's not `.*?`

Comment: The question-mark `.*?` is still required. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/XSu22/4/

Comment: huh, okay :)  For some reason I was thinking the look-ahead would prevent it from passing the first `D0*`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(.+?)D0\*/
```

Try it here: http://rubular.com/r/TNTizJLSn9

Comment: In this particular case, is the `^` necessary?

Comment: @Sime For the same effect as `substr(0)`, yes. If your string does not repeat this pattern though, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number-group, like your example.

```
/^(.*?)foo/
```

It mean somethink like:

- Store all in group, from start (the `0`)
- Stop, but don't store on found `foo` (the `indexOf`)

After that, you need match and get

```
'hello foo bar foo bar'.match(/^(.*?)foo/)[1]; // will return "hello "
```

It mean that will work on `str` variable and get the first (and unique) number-group existent. The `[0]` instead `[1]` mean that will get all matched code.

Bye :)